# Triggering Jenkins job from another jenkins job on same jenkins server getting 443: Connection refused

Tags: jenkins, subprocess

I have a python script inside which I am using the subprocess module(using curl commands) to trigger a job JOB-B.

The python script is called from execute shell of another job JOB-A . Both the jobs are on same jenkins machine.

When I try to run the script locally through my code editor it runs successfully. But when I build the JOB-A it doesn't triggers the JOB-B, while trying to hit the JOB-B api it gives connection refused error.

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n    
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0curl: (7) Failed to connect to mydomain.com port 443: Connection refused\n'))
```

This is my code snippet where I am trying to hit the api of JOB-B.

```
cmd = ["curl", "-k", "--noproxy", "*", job_b_last_build_link]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0].decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

So basically first I want to check the last build status from the above api.

Comment: Do you have authentication on??

Comment: Does Jenkins run with HTTPS? as it looks like the API is being called against port 443 (HTTPS) so it could be either.  The Jenkins is HTTP only, the API is not presenting a Certificate and is being rejected.  Does the script work when run off a "dev" box?

Comment: @apr_1985 Triggering with http gives 80: connection refused

Comment: The host file has entry like -> 127.0.0.1 localhost, I was thinking there should another entry like private_ip mydomain.com, am I thinking correct?